# Judge didn't receive my submitted evidence!

Tags: evidence

I submitted documents at the surrogate's office for evidence in my case but the judge claimed that they didnt have anything submitted from me. This is a civil case and unfortunately I cannot afford a lawyer. What reason(s) would cause the documents not be put In my case file?

Comment: There's too many reasons to guess, and we can not give legal advice. Courts have usually very strict rules on how to submit any evidence and the format.

Answer (score 6):

When you submit documents, the court clerk who receives them (and, supposedly, attaches to the file) is supposed (or, at least, can be asked) to confirm that they have been filed.

You should obtain this confirmation from the clerk, and then present it to the judge.